# PHP - SQL query only shows last result

Tags: php

This only returns the last one of my rows:

```html
<?php
    function all_infos_query() {
     global $connection;
     
     $query  = "SELECT * ";
     $query .= "FROM pages ";
     $query .= "JOIN subjects ";
     $query .= "ON pages.subject_id=subjects.id";
     $infos_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
     confirm_query($infos_set);
     return $infos_set;
    }
   
    
    function infos_content() {
     $infos_set = all_infos_query();  
     
     while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($infos_set)) {
      $output = htmlentities($info["content"]);
      $output .= " <br><br>";
     }
     mysqli_free_result($infos_set);
     return $output;
     
    }
   ?>
            
            <?php echo infos_content() ?>
```

If I echo it like this it works (returns all rows):

```html
<?php 
$result = all_infos_query();

if($result === FALSE) { 
 echo "query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}
else {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo htmlentities($row['content']);
  echo "<br><br>";
 }
}
?>
```

What do I have to change in the function infos_content() to also get all the rows?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you redefine $ouput for every result

```
while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($infos_set)) {
                    $output = htmlentities($info["content"]); 
                    $output .= " <br><br>";
```

Instead, create $ouput outside the loop and append to it..

```
 $output ='';
while($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($infos_set)) {
                    $output .= htmlentities($info["content"]); 
                    $output .= " <br><br>";
```